# JASA Tex archive

Tags: templates

Im a beginner using latex and I was very happy writting my paper for JASA (Journal of the acoustical society of America and found out that ASA end their support to JASAtex. Wonder if somebody wants to share a tex template with me. Please.

Comment: The JASA provides [this page](http://jasa.peerx-press.org/html/jasa/Using_LaTeX_for_JASA.html), which has guidelines and sample code for the journal.

Comment: Yes, but I was just wondering if a more experienced tex user want to share a template with me. Im a lyx user, not a latex user.

Comment: @MarioRiveraChavarria: You need to be clear about your question. There is a distinct difference between the use of TeX, or LaTeX or LyX for that matter.

Comment: Since I cant use lyx, and Im a beginner in latex, wonder if somebody wants to share a latex JASA submission template.

Comment: @MarioRiveraChavarria: You can use LyX, I guess, but you didn't request that "restriction" in your question.